# PHP ArrayUndefinedOffset But Why?

Tags: php, arrays, undefined, offset

I have dataset like the following, one of my table column let say prices column store prices in json format, example given below.

```
<?php 
       $dataSet[] = array(
            "product_id" => 1,
            "prices" => '{"1":"29990", "2": "10000"}'
        );

        foreach ($dataSet as $dataRow) 
        {
            $pricesStdClassObject = json_decode($dataRow['prices']);

            // Convert stdClass Object into array
            $pricesArray = (array) $pricesStdClassObject;

            print_r($pricesArray);
        }
?>
```

The output of **print_r($pricesArray)** is the following

```
    Array ( [1] => 29990 [2] => 10000 )
```

Then why **print_r($pricesArray[1])** give me error

```
    A PHP Error was encountered
    Severity: Notice
    Message: Undefined offset: 1
```

**But why?**

Comment: _"The output should be like the following"_ - so what _is_ the output? Can you read [ask] and provide a [mcve]? There's quite some irrelevant code here, and the actual output is missing.

Comment: If you look at the foreach body i debugging the $pricesArray which out Array ( [1] => 29990 [2] => 10000 ) in the browser mean it's an array but when i access the first index value e.g echo $pricesArray[1] why it gives me undefined offset

Comment: Any help or suggestion plz?

Comment: Your code prints `Array ( [1] => 29990 [2] => 10000 )` for me.

Comment: yes but if you try to getting the index 1 value then it will give you error

Comment: i think the array typecasting is not working properly with std Class Object.

Answer (score 0):

**And finally i found the solution:**

According to the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and from the forum [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45959) I found a **‘assoc’** parameter of **json_decoded** method that used with this method and by default its value is **FLASE**, **json_decoded** return **stdClass object**s if you want the returned **object**s converted into associative **array**s then you have to make the **‘assoc’** parameter value to **TRUE** like the following.

```
$pricesStdClassObject = json_decode($dataRow['prices'], TRUE);
```

So the above example code will become like this

```
<?php 
       $dataSet[] = array(
            "prices" => '{"1":"29990", "2": "10000"}'
        );

        foreach ($dataSet as $dataRow) 
        {
            $pricesArray = json_decode($dataRow['prices'], TRUE);

            // returned objects will be converted into associative arrays. 
            print_r($pricesArray);
        }
?>
```

And then you can access the indexed value with no error message :)

```
         print_r($pricesArray[1]);    output: 29990
```

**Array type casting** with **json decoded StdClass Object**s is not working properly, you can skip the following piece of code if you are using the **‘assoc’** parameter.

```
     // Convert stdClass Object into array
     $pricesArray = (array) $pricesStdClassObject;
```